# Bootstrap Navbar is longer then actual content on the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I couldn't find an answer that could really help me out so I decided to ask it (sorry if this has already been asked but I need an answer cause it's annoying me for days now.)[As you can see in the picture the navbar is way too long for the actual page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAdLK.jpg)

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Afterburners.be - Homepage</title>

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<!-- Navigation -->

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container" role="navigation">
     <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <p><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Afterburners</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="kalender.html">Kalender</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="spelregels.html">Spelregels</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Teams <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="jeugd.html">Jeugd</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="volwassenen.html">Volwassenen</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<p><img src="images/header.jpg" alt="header" width="100%" height="100%" /></p>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <img src="images/Welkom.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </div>

    </div>

    <hr />
    <!-- /.row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="kalender.html">Kalender</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="contact.html">Contact</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="spelregels.html">Spelregels</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="volwassenen.html">Volwassenen</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="jeugd.html">Jeugd</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer style="color:white">

        <p>Afterburners.be &copy; 2016</p>

    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <span class="right"><!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} --></span>
    <p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/hodbafterburners">Facebook</a></p>
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fhodbafterburners&amp;width=100&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=false&amp;height=80&amp;appId=139068449493341" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</footer>
<!--footer end-->
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000 //changes the speed
})
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.dezelfdegrootte img{
min-height:29em;
max-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

body{
background:
linear-gradient(27deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 0 5px,
linear-gradient(207deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 0px,
linear-gradient(27deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 0px 10px,
linear-gradient(207deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 5px,
linear-gradient(90deg, #1b1b1b 10px, transparent 10px),
linear-gradient(#1d1d1d 25%, #1a1a1a 25%, #1a1a1a 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 75%, #242424 75%, #242424);
background-color: #131313;
background-size: 20px 20px;
}

h1{
    color:white;
}

hr{
    color: white;
}

.sponsor{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-default{
    display: flex;
    margin:0 auto;
    align-items:center;
}

.btn-default:hover{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

If anyone could help me out with this problem that would be awesome!

Comment: I'm going to be bold and say your navbar is correct, your markup for your content is likely using the wrong classes. Any chance of a jsFiddle?

Comment: If you could provide some CSS for these elements that would be great and help make us better understand what's happening.

Comment: It's just standard bootstrap css so I tought it wasn't needed to share the css.

Comment: @soloughlin3 I added the CSS I added so you can see if maybe i did something wrong in there :o

Comment: and @AndyHolmes No I dont think there's any jsFiddle involved

Comment: @JeffVanAelst Haha no i meant can you make a jsFiddle so we can try and replicate the issue

Answer (score 0):

[Seems like using a different browser on my phone also did the trick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqZWo.jpg)

seems like there was no problem at all sorry for the misunderstanding guys ^-^

Answer (score -2):

It looks to me like the android device; rather than the markup or CSS. I just viewed it in Safari in a few different devices and it renders absolutely fine see.

[afterburners.be on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzSjM.png)

Comment: is there any way to fix it for android then though?

Comment: This is not an android thing - its a screen size thing. Resize it in your desktop browser and it will start looking weird.

Comment: just tried it out on my ipad and it works fine there too it's only not working on my own phone(android) I'll ask people I know to test it out on their phones to see if it's working for them or not (eventough that wont solve my problem haha)

Comment: and @Novocaine it's behaving just fine in my desktop browser

Comment: What happens when you rotate the android device to landscape?